# Perl compiler for Windows

Tags: windows, perl, compiler-construction, module, executable

I'm trying to compile a Perl script on Windows 7 x64 SP1 so that it can run on a computer that does not have Perl installed. I tried tinyperl, Perl2Exe, perl dev kit but I can't compile the file. I thought I'd include the modules in the executable that I need but do not know how to do it. Can someone can help me?

Comment: error messages? what happens?

Comment: You might find this thread helpful: http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=333584

Comment: Perhaps you can post the script so that others may try?

Comment: Also, this looks to be helpful for you: http://www.cava.co.uk/

Comment: i think, OP search for strawberry and pp <- package for compile perl files

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying can be done with `pp`, which is a part of `PAR::Packer` library. In my case, I've never successfully messed with 64 bit perl, so my advice is to use a 32bit perl distribution (ActivePerl or Strawberry perl will do just fine). 
To use pp, install PAR::Packer from cpan, install a windows version of gcc (miniGW) and instruct your Perl to use that compiler. A rather outdated (but effective) guide on how to integrate miniGW with Perl is found [here:](http://panospace.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/perl-in-windows/). To get a good idea if pp is for you (if it is not, there's nothing that can do your job) check [the appropriate cpan page for the module](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/PAR-0.85_01/script/pp)